# Rails roo, Integer value is converted by datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roo-gem

I'm trying to read xlsx file using roo gem, and I have a problem.

> When I read a integer value '693837900371', rails convert 'Sat, 19 Feb 1899665549'.

I do not find any solution to solve it.

Comment: I think it's stored as a date in the excel sheet, inspect it using microsoft excel and look if the field is a datefield

Comment: I checked my xlsx file, the type of value is 'number'.